# Maintain data in redirection between different URLs in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have just started to learn Spring MVC. So, sorry if my beginner level irritates you.

To have my question short and clear i am using following simple code example.

i have two functions in two different spring MVC controllers.
In first controller, i am having:

```
@RequestMapping("/first")
public String first(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", "User Name");
    return "redirect:/second";
}
```

In second controller i am having:

```
@RequestMapping("/second")
public String second(){
    return "myView";
}
```

Actually the first is redirecting to the second. Bt in my view(html), when i try to get model's value like:

```
<h1>Welcome! ${user} <h1>   //code in html to get user object
```

It shows empty.

So my question is how to transfer data when you are redirecting between two requests in spring MVC. what is the best solution to achieve this. Can i achieve this by **Model** or some other approach is there...?
Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Flash Attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning with

```
return "redirect:/second";
```

causes the `DispatcherServlet` to return a 302 response code with a `Location` header telling your client where to actually look for the page. In your case, go look for it at `./second`. If you made the request through a browser, this will result in the browser sending a new HTTP GET request to the URL in the `Location` header.

`Model` attributes, like `HttpServletRequest` attributes only exist in the context of a single request. Since what you are doing happens over two requests, the attributes in the first won't exist in the second. You need to use Flash Attributes.

Spring 3.1 provides the [`RedirectAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) class to achieve flash attributes. You can add a parameter of type `RedirectAttributes` to your handler method and use the `addFlashAttribute()` method to add attributes that will be added to your model in the next request.

```
@RequestMapping("/first")
public String first(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("user", "User Name");
    return "redirect:/second";
}
```

What this does under the covers is it adds the attributes added by `addFlashAttribute` to the `HttpSession` attributes with a special key. In the next request, the `DispatcherServlet` adds all `HttpSession` attributes with that special key into the `Model`.